# How to check if element is clickable in a loop in protractor?

Tags: node.js, protractor

i want to check if `new_button` is clickable in the loop, if this element is clickable, i want to stop the loop. Here is my loop:

```
  for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        await items[i].click()
    
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(datepicker), waitLongTime);
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(provider_filter_button), waitLongTime);
    
        if(await (new_button.isClickable())) {
           break;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a trick that you can do in this case.

[ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) returns a functions that returns a promise that resolves into boolean - `true` if passed element is clickable, `false` if not.

Therefore, 2 things to keep in mind:

1. Since it returns a function you need to call it. Pay attention to the parenthesis at the end:

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(new_button)() // <---
```

2. The function returns a Promise which needs to be resolved with `await`:

```
await ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(new_button)() // <---
```

So you'll end up having

```
if(await ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(new_button)()) {
    break;
}
```

There might be a better, cleaner way for doing this, but this approach is 100% valid